# Data column into db MVC4

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

```
        <table>
        @foreach (DataRow row in Model.Rows)
        {        
            <tr>
                @foreach (DataColumn col in Model.Columns)
                {             
                    <td>@row[col.ColumnName]</td>
                }
            </tr>
        }
    </table>

    @Html.ActionLink("Pass", "Insert", "Home")
```

When clicking the pass link i would like the columns to be inserted into db. Is there any tutorial on how to do this?

Comment: `ActionLink()` is for a GET method. If your wanting to insert data into a database, you need a POST (and what are you intending to 'insert' anyway - your not editing anything

Comment: This information is displayed and then needs to be approved to be inserted

Comment: The you need form to post the data. All you need is to include the ID of that record as a route value and the form would post to (say) `pubic ActionResult Approve(int ID)`

Comment: But its very unclear what your wanting to generate in the view - you have a row for each record but only 1 'link' - do you want to approve all records at once, or just one of the records? And using a `DataTable` in the view is awful practice. Create a view model to represent your data.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this sample.
Create a view model class as follows

```
public class DataRows
{
    public int Column1{ get; set; }
    public string Column2 { get; set; }
    public double Column3 { get; set; }
}

public class MyModel
{
    public virtual DataRows[] DataSet { get; set; }
}
```

Retrieve all the data using your business logic into **MyModel** in your controller. I am demonstrating this using a sample code

```
    public TestModel GenerateModel()
    {
         var model = new TestModel();
         model.DataSet = this.GenerateDataGridData().ToArray();
         return model;
     }

    private ICollection<SampleDataSet> GenerateDataGridData()
    {
        var list = new List<SampleDataSet>() 
           { 
             new SampleDataSet() { Column1= 1, Column2= "XXX", Column3= 23 }, 
             new SampleDataSet() { Column1= 2, Column2= "YYY", Column3= 27 }, 
             new SampleDataSet() { Column1= 3, Column2= "ZZ", Column3= 25 } 
           };
        return list;
  }
```

In the Action of your view you will be calling **GenerateModel** method as follows

```
public ActionResult MyView()
 {
    var model = this.GenerateModel();
    return this.View(model);
 }
```

Now you restructure your **MyView** page as follows

```
@model MyModel

@{
    int i = 0;
}
@using (Html.BeginForm("Insert", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
{
    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Column1</th>
                <th>Column2</th>
                <th>Column3</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            @foreach (var row in Model.DataSet)
            {
                <tr>
                    <th>@row.Column1<span>@Html.HiddenFor(x => Model.DataSet[i].Column1)</span></th>
                    <th>@row.Column2<span>@Html.HiddenFor(x => Model.DataSet[i].Column2)</span></th>
                    <th>@row.Column3<span>@Html.HiddenFor(x => Model.DataSet[i].Column3)</span></th>
                </tr>
                i++;
            }
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <input type="submit" value="Pass" />
}
```

Now on submiting the data in the view will be posted to your **Insert** Action of Home controller and you can insert into your DB using your logic

I hope this will be a solution for your query.